# Passing a function pointer with it's own parameters in C

Tags: c, parameters, scope, function-pointers, function-prototypes

```
#include <stdio.h>

void runner(void (* function)(int in)){
  (*function)(in); 
}

void print(int in){
 printf("%d\n", in);
}

int main(){
 // 
 return 0;
}
```

Above code is not compiling and shows this error: `'in' undeclared`.

Do I have to pass the parameters of a `function pointer` separately like this?

```
void runner(void (* function)(int), int in){
  (*function)(in); 
}
```

i.e form a syntax point of view, there is no way to pass the function pointer and its argument all at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters are not passed. It is arguments that are passed.

So this function declaration

```
void runner(void (* function)(int in)){
  (*function)(in); 
}
```

has only one parameter: a pointer to a function, But if you want to call the pointed function that expects an argument then you need to supply an argument.

In this declaration of a function pointer

```
void (* function)(int in)
```

the function parameter `in` has the function prototype scope..

You may declare the function parameter without its identifier like

```
void (* function)(int)
```

So you have to declare the function with two parameters like

```
void runner(void (* function)(int), int in ){
  function(in); 
}
```

Pay attention to that to dereference the pointer to function is redundant.

All these calls as for example

```
( *function )( int );
```

or

```
( *****function )( in );
```

are equivalent to

```
function( in );
```

Comment: Actually this function could be written as `void runner(void function(int), int in ){
  function(in); 
}`. It takes advantage from fact that parameters of function types are automagically transformed to pointers to functions. Similar to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

When declaring types from function types the argument names are ignored.
Thus the definition is equivalent to:

```
void runner(void (* function)(int)){
  (*function)(in); 
}
```

and identifier `in` is indeed undeclared.

Passing a function with some of its argument would form a closure that are not natively supported by C.

Alternatively, GCC supports an extension for nested function that can access automatic variables of embedding function.

```
void runner(void (* function)()){
  function(); 
}

int main(){
  int in = 10;
  void print(){
     printf("%d\n", in);
  }
  runner(print);
 return 0;
}
```